# Set a cookie whenever front page is viewed

Tags: 7, cookies

I run [a Drupal 7 site](http://preferans.de) (currently 7.15) since longer time and have the problem with cookies:

I need 2 cookies for non-Drupal PHP-scripts at my web site.

I set them in the hook_init of my custom module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_login().
 */
function pref_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
    if ($account->uid <= 0) {
      return;
    }

    #drupal_set_message('<p>Hello, '.$account->name.'</p>');
    $auth  = md5(join('_', array($account->uid, MY_SECRET)));
    $year  = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 12;
    setcookie('pref_id', $account->uid, $year, '/', '.preferans.de');
    setcookie('pref_auth', $auth, $year, '/', '.preferans.de');
}
```

The problem is, that I need to set the both cookies each time a logged in user visits the front page and not just when the user logs in.

Does anybody please have an idea how to do it, maybe by JavaScript if I can't do it regular way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do this in hook_preprocess_page() and instead of setting a variable, you could do something like this:

```
function pref_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  global $user;

  // whatever other preprocess stuff you want to do here

  if ($user->uid && drupal_is_front_page()) { 
    $auth  = md5(join('_', array($user->uid, MY_SECRET)));
    $year  = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 12;
    setcookie('pref_id', $account->uid, $year, '/', '.preferans.de');
    setcookie('pref_auth', $auth, $year, '/', '.preferans.de');
  }

}
```

Comment: You might have to clear the Drupal cache before you see new preprocess_page hooks working...